# Docker image from loca dev machine on dev windows to linux machine

Tags: docker, spring-boot, deployment, dockerfile, docker-container

I have created a simple spring-boot app and created an image of it using `docker build Dockerfile`.
I want to upload this image to a Linux machine and spin up the container there, Where I could find the image of this app to push it to Linux machine?
I am using Docker toolbox to run docker commands on Windows 10 Home edition.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to push a docker image you need a registry. Public images can be pushed through hub.docker.com. Private containers can be pushed through private registries. There are lots of registries like: `nexus 3` & `gitlab`.

so in a nutshell you need to do:

- install a docker registry on a machine which both your dev machine and prod machine can access
- Configure the registry endpoints for access
- login to the private registry through docker
- Tag your image for the registry
- push the image
- go to the server
- pull the image from the private registry
- run it on the server

OR

- without a registry
- build the image again on the linux machine
- run it from the linux machine from the local build

good luck